# How to use the GNU scientific library (gsl) in nvidia Nsight eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, cuda, gsl, nsight

I would like to use some gsl functions in my CUDA code. (in Nsight eclipse on linux) I have installed gsl and now I should setup the linker setting in eclipse.

I have tried to follow the steps outlined 
[here](http://bitsandbusiness.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/gnu-scientific-library-gsl-undefined-reference-problem-eclipse-linking/), but I have some issues. In the project properties there is no "C/C++ Build" menu only "Build"  and I was not able to find the setting mentioned in the above blog post.

How can I setup the linker settings ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use gsl routines directly in CUDA device code.  The gsl libraries (`-lgsl`) are compiled for x86 usage and will not run on a GPU.

If you only want to use gsl routines in host code, it should be sufficient to simply specify the include file and path, the linker path, and the linker library:

```
-I/usr/local/include/gsl
-L/usr/local/lib (or /usr/local/lib64)
-lgsl
```

Here's [a question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148814/how-to-link-to-cublas-library-in-eclipse-nsight) discussing how to make these kind of additions in nsight eclipse

Comment: Thanks Robert!
I sort of understand that vector and matrix manipulations should not work on the GPU but what about simple functions like Bessel function. Would that work on the GPU?

Comment: Not if it references code that has been compiled in a x86 library.  GPUs do not execute x86 code directly, not even simple functions.

Comment: Note that CUDA provides the Bessel functions of the first and second kind, as specified by Posix: j0(), j1(), jn(), y0(), y1(), yn(). CUDA 6.0 added the modified Bessel functions of the first kind of order 0 and 1: cyl_bessel_i0(), cyl_bessel_i1(). If you need additional Bessel functions, I would suggest filing an enhancement request via the bug reporting form linked from the registered developer website.